# How to translate a form in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a form in a django site

```
<form method="POST" action="." class="right_custom">{% csrf_token %}
    <br>{% trans "Enter the discount coupon code if you have any" %}</br>
    <input type="text" name="coupon_code"  size="25" maxlength="25" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Caluclate Discount"/>
</form>
```

I would like to translate the entire site to a lot of languages. I need to translate the button text which is `Caluclate Discount`. How can I do that? if i use `{% trans %}` tag, how will the view catch the right post request?

*UPDATE*

There are many forms on the same page like this and my view uses `if postdata['submit']=="Caluclate Discount"` to determine which submit request it is.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the translation working.

Thanks to the answers by @linux-warrior and @Joachim

Now the form is

```
<form method="POST" action="." class="right_custom">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="discount_form" />
    <br>{% trans "Enter the discount coupon code if you have any" %}</br>
    <input type="text" name="coupon_code"  size="25" maxlength="25" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="{% trans "Caluclate Discount" %}" />
</form>
```

And i check for if `postdata['form_name']=='discount_form'` in my view

Answer (score 1):

For buttons, you really don't use the value field for anything else than the button text, so it is straightforward to translate:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="{% trans "Caluclate Discount" %}"/>
```

Comment: but my view checks for if `postdata['submit']=="Caluclate Discount"`. Would not that cause a problem?

Comment: @user1077344 You mean you distinguish forms by the submit button? Why not use a hidden form input element instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use {% trans %} for submit "value". I don't understand why would you need that value inside your view. If you want, you can still give your submit input a custom "name" attribute.

**Edit**. By the way, your

```
<br>...</br>
```

thing inside your form appears to be a bug. You will probably want to make it

```
<p>...</p>
```

instead. It is also not recommended to use "submit" name for a type="submit" input (taken from http://api.jquery.com/submit/):

> Forms and their child elements should not use input names or ids that conflict with properties of a form, such as submit, length, or method. Name conflicts can cause confusing failures. For a complete list of rules and to check your markup for these problems, see [DOMLint](http://kangax.github.com/domlint/).

Comment: You can then do the check like : if 'your_submit_button_name' in request.POST

Answer (score 0):

Your view doesn't care about what is the submit button's value, so even if you translate it, your view function will work.

Comment: but my view checks for `if postdata['submit']=="Caluclate Discount"`